# Alma Linux 9 - Fail to install old version of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I follow the Jenkins install instruction "https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#long-term-support-release-3" of Jenkins.
Progress of Key, GPC, and Package is normal.
At the last step, when performing install an old version of Jenkins. It encounters error

Command install: `sudo yum install jenkins-2.138.2`
Error:
`Public key for jenkins-2.138.2-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction. You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'. Error: GPG check FAILED`